# Automatically collapse or fold getters and setters or use compact format in NetBeans?

Tags: java, netbeans

The question is pretty self explainatory, is there a way to have NetBeans automatically collapse/fold `getter` `setter` methods into code blocks?

I find they take too much space and have nothing interesting in them. I've tried using a more compact notation such as `getField{return field;}` but when I have NetBeans format the code it gets changed back automatically to the standard, more roomy format.

If this isn't possible, is there a way to change the default formatting to the more compact way I mentioned?

[image: getters and setters compact format demostration]

Answer (score 4):

You can configure this in **Tools / Options / Editor / General**

There you have a few code collapse configuration options: **Code Foldings** / **Collapse by Default**

Comment: There is no option for collapsing `getters` and `setters` there and I wouldn't like to have every method collapse by default.

Comment: In NetBeans 8 to be found in Tools / Options / Editor / Folding (I find it useful to collapse imports by default).

Answer (score 1):

I found some way to do that, and it's specific for Netbeans
 http://andreamoz.blogspot.com.es/2009/09/how-to-fold-code-in-netbeans.html

> How to fold code in NetBeans
>
> NetBeans editor has always had several nice features, one of which is the possibility to fold code thus eliminating unnecessary noise when working. Normally you can collapse methods, comments, imports, javadocs, and so on just clicking the + sign on the left (or using the CTRL + KeyPad- combination). To expand the collapsed section you can obviously click on the - or use the CTRL + KeyPad+ combination.
>
> NetBeans also offers you the possibility to arbitrarily collapse contiguous lines of code: all you have to do is select the lines you want to collapse and press ALT + Enter, thus showing available suggestions given the context (in our case
> Surround with //...)

Comment: please provide a full answer, not just a link

Comment: For me CTRL+KeyPad- only worked within a method, not when marking multiple methods. The ALT-Enter and then Surround with worked.

Answer (score 0):

To collapse getters and setter automatically when generated, you have to edit the getters and setters template. and that means editing the Netbeans source code. because generating getters and setters is not in the code completion templates.

For now its easier to click the '-' to collapse